# Maximum gap in unsorted array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm following algorithm from here:

> [http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/dm-reading-assignments/Maximum-Gap-Problem.pdf](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Egodfried/teaching/dm-reading-assignments/Maximum-Gap-Problem.pdf)

I dont understand step 2 and 3:

> 2. Divide  the  interval  [x­min, x­max]  into (n−1)  "buckets"  of  equal size  delta= (x­max – x­min)/(n‐1)
> 3. For  each  of  the  remaining  (n‐2)  numbers  determine  in  which  bucket it  falls  using  the  floor  function.  The  number  xi  belongs  to  the  kth  bucket  Bk  if,  and  only  if,  (xi ‐ x­min)/δ = k‐1.

Lets say
a = [13, 4, 7, 2, 9, 17, 18]

Minm:  2 Maxm:  18 n-1:  6.
So my # of buckets will be 6. And delta = (18-2)/6 = 2. That is 6 buckets
having 2 elements into each of them. (Total 12 elements I can have)

Step 2. Que:
If there are only 12 elements where would be my max 18?

Step 3.
For element 18:
as per algorithm it should be in math.floor((17-2)/float(2)) = 7
So 18 should be in 8th block, BUT we have only (n-1) = 6 buckets.

Mystery to me!

EDIT1:
Sorry
Step 3: wrong Math:
math.floor((17-2)/float(2)) = 5
Still need to figure out where does minimum and maximum goes.

EDIT2:
As per answer by Miljen Mikic:
He was right, my question is "What we do with maximum and minimum"
And in step 6:

> In  L  find  the  maximum  distance  between  a  pair  of  consecutive  minimum  and maximum (xi­max, xj­min),  where  j > i.

How come j > i? i.e. max from next bucket and min from current bucket.

Comment: You could ask which buckets can possibly contain one of the numbers defining the maximum gap, question the wisdom to compute all those differences to the bucket's walls, whether it is necessary to insert many numbers into any given bucket in the first place, what would constitute a tight upper bound on the number of comparisons - none of which is anything to do with the point of the assignment.

Comment: You applied the floor function to δ, where it is uncalled for: δ is 8/3 (close to 2.67), not 2. In the suggestion, min and max don't go into any bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the algorithm you cited, you don't put minimum and maximum in the buckets. Pay attention to the Note after Step 5:

> Note: Since there are n-1 buckets and only n-2 numbers..

If you put minimum and maximum in some buckets, then you would have had `n` numbers, not `n-2`. The real question now is: what to do with minimum and maximum? Actually, step 6 of the algorithm should be clarified a little bit more. When you examine the list L, you should start with `x-min` and compare it with `x1-min`, and you should end by comparing `x(n-1)-max` and `x-max`, because the maximum gap can actually include minimum or maximum, like you get e.g. in this example: [1,7,3,2]. Of course, these two additional comparisons still give you linear time complexity.

Note that you can change the algorithm slightly by putting minimum and maximum in buckets as well (by the exact same formula!) and then you would have `n` numbers and `n` buckets. Why? Minimum always goes in the first bucket (see the formula), and maximum needs to go in the `n`-th bucket, which didn't exist previously, so we have one extra bucket if we apply this change. This means that in this case you cannot always apply Pigeonhole principle, however it still holds that the maximum  distance  between  a  pair  of  consecutive elements  must  be  at  least  the  length  of  the  bucket. How come? If at least one bucket contains two elements, then there must be some empty bucket and this is clear. Otherwise, all buckets contain exactly one element; this means that the first bucket contains the minimum, and the second bucket contains an element whose value is at least `x_min + δ`, so the difference between this element and `x_min` is at least `δ`, the  length  of  the  bucket. Why the element in the second bucket has to be at least `x_min + δ`? If it is smaller than that, e.g. if it's `x_min + δ - k`, where `k > 0`, then it will also belong to the first bucket because `[((x_min + δ - k) - x_min) / δ] = [(δ - k) / δ] = 0`, i.e. not to the second as we assumed!

Comment: you're right about "what to do with min and max". But in your answer do you mean Step 6 than the step 5?

Comment: Seems like if I add numbers, its fine finding distance in between (e.g. [5,2,20,17,3])                                                                                           Delta:  4.0
Buckets:  {2: [], 6: [], 10: [], 14: [], 18: [], 20: []}
Buckets:  {2: [5, 2, 3], 6: [], 10: [], 14: [17], 18: [20], 20: []}
L :  [(2, 5), (17, 17), (20, 20)]
MAX DISTNACE: 12

Comment: But not good with your example:                                                                    Delta:  2.0
Buckets:  {1: [], 3: [], 5: [], 7: []}
Buckets:  {1: [1, 2], 3: [3], 5: [], 7: [7]}
L :  [(1, 2), (3, 3), (7, 7)]
4

Comment: @codemuncher Yes, I meant Step 6. The second part of my answer required is now significantly extended and cleared, hope this helps.